# $scope variable isn't recognized when calling initialization function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have the following code, where I want to receive all the texts from the current user and show them on screen when the page loads:

```
angular.module('eddieApp')
    .controller('MainController', function ($scope, Principal, TextService) {

        $scope.texts = [];

        Principal.identity().then(function(account) {
            $scope.account = account;
            $scope.isAuthenticated = Principal.isAuthenticated;
        });

        $scope.findByUser = function(){
            TextService.findByUser($scope.account.login).success(function(data){
                $scope.texts = data;
            });
        };

        // receive all notes from current user
        $scope.$watch(function(scope) { return scope.account; },
                      function()      { $scope.findByUser(); });


    });
```

The problems is that it works, but I don't understand why is this the only method to make it work.

I tried to call the function `$scope.findByUser()` like this:

```
angular.module('eddieApp')
    .controller('MainController', function ($scope, Principal, TextService) {

    $scope.texts = [];

    Principal.identity().then(function(account) {
        $scope.account = account;
        $scope.isAuthenticated = Principal.isAuthenticated;
    });

    $scope.findByUser = function(){
        TextService.findByUser($scope.account.login).success(function(data){
            $scope.texts = data;
        });
    };

    $scope.findByUser();

});
```

but I get an error saying that `$scope.account.login` isn't recognized.

Also, I tried to put the directive `ng-init="findByUser()"` in my html code, but again, I get the same error saying that `$scope.account.login` isn't recognized.

Finally i made it work with the `$watch` function, but I don't understand why the first two methods didn't work, because they are easier to understand and I would preffer using them instead of `$watch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works because your `$watch` ensures that `$scope.account` is defined before running `$scope.findByUser`.

In your example without the watch, `findByUser` executes immediately, and tries to use the `login` property of `$scope.account` which is undefined.

If having a user account is a prerequisite of `findByUser`, and there's nothing in your view that calls it immediately, it may make more sense to call `findByUser` in your `then` block, which would avoid the need for a `$watch`.

Comment: I had a hunch that this is the reason and now hearing from someone else I am convinced. Thanks!

Comment: @Adel glad to hear it. Feel free to accept the answer if it does indeed answer your question.